# Indesign question regarding "placed" objects

Tags: adobe-indesign

As a total newb, I am more than sure that I'm the problem...  I'm trying to place five pieces of b/w original artwork into a document.  I've resized all images to a similar size.
After placing them in the new document, I see that they have lost resolution and appear blurry.
Is this a function of having re-sized them (in photoshop) or is there something I should be doing in Indesign to correct them?

Comment: All images are by default shown as a low quality preview. Everything should look ok after exporting.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on CAI's comment, indeed InDesign will work by default in a Typical Display performance, which means links are rendered in a low-res preview to improve general performance and speed, which is more likely a problem with large volume files.

To view your links in a full resolution preview go to Main Menu > View > Display Performance > High Quality Display

This will be opposed to the Typical Display setting that you get by default.

If this won't work, then the next logical assumption would be your placed files are broken links, meaning they have been moved from their original drive location after placing them in ID, in which case you should update the links to their current location or easier, just delete the images and place them again.